# UI router same controller for multiple states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application, angular-ui-router-extras

In my Angular JS application, I have 2 views - v1 and v2 and 1 controller - appCtrl.

I have configured UI router as below

```
          .state('profile.v1', {
            url: '/v1',
            templateUrl: 'v1.html',
            controller: 'appCtrl'
        })
          .state('profile.v2', {
            url: '/v2',
            templateUrl: 'v2.html',
            controller: 'appCtrl'
        })
```

I have 2 functions in appCtrl - fv1 and fv2.

I want to execute fv1 when route '/v1' is called, fv2 when route '/v2' is called.

Can somebody suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inject `$state` into the controller, and check `$state.current.name` - It should be `profile.v1` or `profile.v2`, depending on what state you're currently in

Answer (score 4):

Another way you can do this with one state declaration is:

```
.state('profile.detail', {
      url: '/:version',
      templateUrl: function($stateParams){             
         return $stateParams.version +'.html';
     },
      controller: 'appCtrl'
})
```

Then inject $stateParams in controller and check `$stateParams.version`